# How to compare two column and how to get how get all rows?

Tags: mysql

I have one table. Here my question is how to find how many rows with same value compare two column.

```
id      true_ans  your_ans que_id    
------+---------+--------+---------
1     |  2      |  2     |  1
2     |  5      |  4     |  3
3     |  8      |  9     |  4
4     |  14     |  14    |  6
5     |  19     |  19    |  7 
6     |  21     |  22    |  9
```

Here i want find how many rows correct answer. Please reply me.

Comment: `select count(*) from table where true_ans=your_ans;`

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CorrectAnswers
FROM YourTable
WHERE 
    true_ans = your_ans
```